# Select command showing options without question

Tags: select

Select command is showing options without displaying question.
It is displaying question after a choice is made.

I have a function as shown below in a script.

```
function start_AppNode
{
    #   Define local variables for all the inputs
    local DName_l=$1
    local ASName_l=$2
    local ANName_l=$3
    
    echo "Do you wish to start the AppNode $ANName_l on AppSpace $ASName_l in Domain $DName_l ?"
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
            Yes ) 
                #print_log $yn
                OUTPUT="`./appadmin start -d $DName_l -as $ASName_l anode $ANName_l`"
                if [[ "$OUTPUT" == *"$SuccessMessage_AppNode_Start"* ]]; then
                    echo "Started"
                else
                    echo "Failed"
                fi
                break;;
            No ) echo "Failed"; break;;
        esac
    done
}
```

When I call that script in an other script where I imported this script, I am getting option first and not showing the question "`Do you wish to start the AppNode $ANName_l on AppSpace $ASName_l in Domain $DName_l ?`"

It shows the question after a choice is being made. See screenshot of output below. Appreciate if anyone can help me understand how to make it show the question first?

[image]

Update:
The issue is due to variable assignment. I am assigning the output of the function to a variable. If I execute the function without assigning the return value to a variable, it works. How can I assign the return value to a variable and still have the question part displayed before the options?

Comment: `select` writes the prompt to `stderr` whilst `echo` writes to `stdout`. If these go directly to a terminal they are interleaved correctly, so there is something you are not telling us, for example that this script has the output piped to say `tee logfile`. Adding `>&2` to the end of the `echo` will probably fix the immediate problem, but might make you need to reconsider your logging choices.

Comment: @icarus, I don't have any redirects in my script or not redirecting the output to any file. As you can see in the screenshot, the Question is displayed with '!' after the selection is made instead of '?'. So, it looks like the select command knows that it skipped to show the question before and showing it after the fact. In the main script I am just calling the command parameters read from a file - `start_AppNode SanityTest SanityAppSpace SanityAppnode_1`  .

Comment: The fact that you are seeing a `!` in the output and have `?` inside double quotes implies strongly that the code you are showing us is not the code you are running. `echo` does not change a `?` inside double quotes even if you have a file named `!` in the current directory.

Comment: @icarus The fact that the text says "stop" rather than "start" is also a fairly strong indicator.

Comment: The `select` command certainly does not `know` that the `question was skipped`.

Comment: Regarding your updated: Why are you assigning the output of the function to a variable? Couldn't you just use the exit status of the function as an indicator of whether it went well or not? Note too that if you write a question to the standard output stream, this would be captured in the caller's command substitution.

Comment: Your update, saying that you are assigning the output of the function to a variable, is another example of the output not going directly to the terminal (it is going to the variable). Presumably in the code you are not showing us you are echoing the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the fact that the code does not generate the output you show you present and will instead focus on how to interact with a user.

The `select` statement displays the menu and prompt on the standard error stream.  It is customary to interact with the user on this stream not to make the user interaction part of the program's standard output stream (which could potentially confuse downstream processes reading the output from the function).

I suggest you output the question to the user on the standard error stream instead of to the standard output stream.  This would make sense as your question has to do with user interaction.

Under *some circumstances*, the standard output and standard error streams may appear interleaved in the terminal. Using a single stream to interact with the user would avoid this.

I would also suggest that you use `printf` rather than `echo` as soon as you have to output variable data:

```bsh
start_AppNode () {
    local DName_l="$1"
    local ASName_l="$2"
    local ANName_l="$3"

    local cmd=( ./appadmin start -d "$DName_l" -as "$ASName_l" anode "$ANName_l" )
    
    printf 'Do you wish to start the AppNode %s on AppSpace %s in Domain %s?\n' \
        "$ANName_l" "$ASName_l" "$DName_l" >&2
    
    local PS3='Start AppNode? '
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        [[ $REPLY == 1 ]] && "${cmd[@]}"
        break
    done |
    if grep -q -F -e "$SuccessMessage_AppNode_Start"; then
        echo Started
    else
        echo Failed
    fi >&2
}
```

If you want the function to provide an exit status that you could use in some main part of the script:

```bsh
start_AppNode () {
    local DName_l="$1"
    local ASName_l="$2"
    local ANName_l="$3"

    local cmd=( ./appadmin start -d "$DName_l" -as "$ASName_l" anode "$ANName_l" )
    
    printf 'Do you wish to start the AppNode %s on AppSpace %s in Domain %s?\n' \
        "$ANName_l" "$ASName_l" "$DName_l" >&2
    
    local PS3='Start AppNode? '
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        [[ $REPLY == 1 ]] && "${cmd[@]}"
        break
    done |
    grep -q -F -e "$SuccessMessage_AppNode_Start"
}
```

Then, later:

```bsh
if start_AppNode "$dn" "$as" "$an"; then
    echo 'Started, good'
else
    echo 'Failed, bad'
fi
```

This `if` statement reads and acts on the function's exit status.  The function's exit status is the exit status of the last statement executed in the function.  This would be the `grep -q` call.  This would be *true* (zero) if whatever string `$SuccessMessage_AppNode_Start` is was found in the output from the `select` statement, and *false* (non-zero) if the string was not found.  The `select` statement conditionally outputs the output of `./appadmin`, or nothing at all, depending on what choices the user makes, the arguments given to the function, and any other number of external factors affecting the output from `./appadmin`.

Comment: Thanks @they. Will check this out.

Answer (score -1):

As @icarus [wrote in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680402/select-command-showing-options-without-question?noredirect=1#comment1285514_680402):

> `select` writes the prompt to `stderr` whilst `echo` writes to
> `stdout`. If these go directly to a terminal they are interleaved
> correctly, so there is something you are not telling us, for example
> that this script has the output piped to say `tee logfile`.

You'll need to make sure that the `echo` is unbuffered. You can run your `echo` with `stdbuf -o0` or `unbuffer` to ensure the question is printed to STDOUT without any buffering.

```
stdbuf -o0 echo "Do you wish to start the AppNode $ANName_l on AppSpace $ASName_l in Domain $DName_l ?"
```

Comment: Tried this and it did not work.


```START -> 2021-12-06_10:12:41.745

2021-12-06 10:12:53.230 : INFO : Successfully stopped the instance of Application InstagramTest.application on AppNode SanityAppnode Success
1) Yes
2) No
#? 1
Do you wish to stop the AppNode SanityAppnode on AppSpace SanityAppSpace in Domain SanityTest !```

Comment: @Anil_4_Tibco_Java, The fact it has a `!` at the end instead of `?` make me think you have a problem with your scripts. The `select` call is not aware of the `echo` before. Those are two unrelated commands, and the `echo` has to show the message as it is, without changing any characters.  If you don't see the question mark at the end, check if you have another implementation of this function in some other (old?) file that you import where you have exclamation mark instead of a question mark at the end. Make some notable change to your `echo` command message to see if it's reflected in the run.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me identify the issue.

I am assigning the output/return value of the function call to a variable.
Making it run without assigning the output to a variable is showing the message as expected.

I am still not sure how '?' is getting replaced with '!', but it is not happening now.

How can I make the return value assigned to a variable and still have the question displayed?